# How to use arcpullr::get_spatial_layer() and arcpullr::get_layer_by_poly()

Tags: api, rest, arcgis

I couldn't figure this out through the package documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arcpullr/vignettes/intro_to_arcpullr.html.

My codes return the errors described below.

```
library(arcpullr)
url <- "https://arcgis.deq.state.or.us/arcgis/rest/services/WQ/WBD/MapServer/1"
huc8_1 <- get_spatial_layer(url)
huc8_2 <- get_layer_by_poly(url,geometry = "esriGeometryPolygon")
```

huc8_1:

> Error in if (layer_info$type == "Group Layer") { :
> argument is of length zero

huc8_2:

> Error in get_sf_crs(geometry) : "sf" %in% class(sf_obj) is not TRUE

It would be very appreciated if you could provide any help to explain the errors and suggest any solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use the `arcpullr` package. Using `leaflet.esri::addEsriFeatureLayer` with a `where` clause works.

See the relevant codes below, as an example:

```
leaflet.esri::addEsriFeatureLayer(
    url="https://arcgis.deq.state.or.us/arcgis/rest/services/WQ/IR_201820_byParameter/MapServer/2",
    options = leaflet.esri::featureLayerOptions(where = IR_where_huc12)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an sf object as the second argument to any of the `get_layer_by_*` functions. I alter your example a bit using a point instead of a polygon for spatial querying (since it's easier to create), but `get_layer_by_poly` would work the same way using an sf polygon instead of a point. Also, the service you use requires a token. I changed the url to [USGS HU 6-digit basins](https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/3) instead

```r
library(arcpullr)
url <- "https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/3"
query_pt <- sf_point(c(-90, 45))
# this would query everything in the feature layer, which may or may not be huge
# huc8_1 <- get_spatial_layer(url)
huc8_2 <- get_layer_by_point(url, query_pt)
huc_map <- plot_layer(huc8_2)
huc_map
huc_map + ggplot2::geom_sf(data = query_pt)
```